# how to swap places of strings in a kotlin list?

Tags: kotlin

i have a list in my project like

```
val list1 = listOf("1", "pig", "3", "cow")
```

and i need to swap it to like `"pig", "1", "cow", "3"`

and the number and words will be random so it cant be only on these words

can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine [chunked()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) to get pairs of items and then [flatMap()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) to swap them and recreate a flat list:

```kotlin
list1
    .chunked(2)
    .flatMap { listOf(it[1], it[0]) } // or: it.reversed()
```

However, it looks pretty weird that you have a list like this in the first place. If items of this list are stored in two subsequent indexes, then such design complicates maintaining and processing of the data. Instead, create a data class for both fields and create a list of such data items:

```kotlin
val list = listOf(Animal("1", "pig"), Animal("3", "cow"))

data class Animal(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
)
```

Comment: Alternatively give the mapping to the chunked function. then you could do `list1.chunked(2){it.reversed()}.flatten()`. It's equally good as your answer I would say, but I thought it was worth mentioning

Comment: i am using a list becaose it is a bot to format data (comunity project :P), people now only need to delete some data to use it, so they dont need to add words

Comment: @IvoBeckers Yes, thank you. I thought about it, because technically speaking it is a little shorter. Maybe this is just me, but I think it is less readable, especially for inexperienced people. Like we do too much in the first step and too less in the second. And we prepare data-to-be-flattened in one step only to flatten it in another. But again, maybe this is just me :-)